# How can I change my C# model list in array format?

Tags: c#, listview, arraylist

I am trying to change my List output to Array as it will be easier to read the json output.

This is the current output:

```
{
  "businessvalue": [
    {
      "BVSId": 1,
      "BVSROI": [
        {
          "BVSROIId": 1,
          "ROIItem": "Subscription Costs",
          "ROIYear": "Initial",
          "ROIYearValue": 10,
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BusinessValue": null
        },
        {
          "BVSROIId": 2,
          "ROIItem": "Subscription Costs",
          "ROIYear": "1",
          "ROIYearValue": 20,
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BusinessValue": null
        },
        {
          "BVSROIId": 3,
          "ROIItem": "Subscription Costs",
          "ROIYear": "2",
          "ROIYearValue": 30,
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BusinessValue": null
        },
        {
          "BVSROIId": 4,
          "ROIItem": "Subscription Costs",
          "ROIYear": "3",
          "ROIYearValue": 40,
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BusinessValue": null
        },
        {
          "BVSROIId": 5,
          "ROIItem": "Subscription Costs",
          "ROIYear": "4",
          "ROIYearValue": 50,
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BusinessValue": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and this is the expected output that I need:

```
    {
      "businessvalue": [
        {
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BVSROI": [
            {
              "BVSROIId": 1,
              "ROIItem": "Subscription Costs",
              "UserInput": [
                {
                  "Initial": 0,
                  "Year1": 10,
                  "Year2": 20,
                  "Year3": 30,


            "Year4": 40
            }
          ],
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BusinessValue": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

currently my model is done this way:

```
namespace WebService.Models
{
    public class BusinessValue
    {
        [Key]
        public int BVSId { get; set; }

        public List<BVSROI> BVSROI { get; set; }
    }

    public class BVSROI
    {
        [Key]
        public int BVSROIId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ROIItem { get; set; }
        public string ROIYear { get; set; }
        public double ROIYearValue { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key
        public int BVSId { get; set; }
        // Navigation property
        public BusinessValue BusinessValue { get; set; }

    }
}
```

I am very new to c# and i hope that you could guide/help me with this.

====

@Rostech,

### I created a separate table

but this is what I've generated:

```
{
  "BusinessValue": [
    {
      "BVSId": 1,
      "Year1": 10,
      "Year2": 20,
      "Year3": 30,
      "CLB": 1,
      "BVSROI": [
        {
          "BVSROIId": 1,
          "ROIItem": "Subscription Costs",
          "UserInput": [
            {
              "BVSROIUIId": 1,
              "ROIYear": "Initial",
              "ROIYearValue": 10,
              "BVSROI": null
            },
            {
              "BVSROIUIId": 2,
              "ROIYear": "1",
              "ROIYearValue": 20,
              "BVSROI": null
            },
            {
              "BVSROIUIId": 3,
              "ROIYear": "2",
              "ROIYearValue": 30,
              "BVSROI": null
            },
            {
              "BVSROIUIId": 4,
              "ROIYear": "3",
              "ROIYearValue": 40,
              "BVSROI": null
            },
            {
              "BVSROIUIId": 5,
              "ROIYear": "4",
              "ROIYearValue": 50,
              "BVSROI": null
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

and the output that I am expecting is like this:

```
 {
      "businessvalue": [
        {
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BVSROI": [
            {
              "BVSROIId": 1,
              "ROIItem": "Subscription Costs",
              "UserInput": [
                {
                  "Initial": 0,
                  "Year1": 10,
                  "Year2": 20,
                  "Year3": 30,


            "Year4": 40
            }
          ],
          "BVSId": 1,
          "BusinessValue": null
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

May model is done this way:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace WebService.Models
{
    public class BusinessValue
    {
        [Key]
        public int BVSId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int Year1 { get; set; }
        public int Year2 { get; set; }
        public int Year3 { get; set; }
        public int CLB { get; set; }
        public List<BVSROI> BVSROI { get; set; }
    }

    public class BVSROI
    {
        [Key]
        public int BVSROIId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ROIItem { get; set; }
        public List<BVSROIUserInput> BVSROIUserInput { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key
        public int BVSId { get; set; }
        // Navigation property
        public BusinessValue BusinessValue { get; set; }

    }

    public class BVSROIUserInput
    {
        [Key]
        public int BVSROIUIId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public string ROIYear { get; set; }
        public double ROIYearValue { get; set; }

        // Foreign Key
        public int BVSROIId { get; set; }
        // Navigation property
        public BVSROI BVSROI { get; set; }

    }

}
```

and this is how i fetch data from the controller:

```
var bvfsroiuis = (from users in db.BusinessValue ...
                  join bvfsroi in db.BVSROIs on bvfs.BVSId equals bvfsroi.BVSId
                  join bvfsroiui in db.BVSROIUserInputs on bvfsroi.BVSROIId equals bvfsroiui.BVSROIId
                  where u.UserId == id 
                   bvfsroiui
                  ).ToList();

List<BVSROIUserInput> bvfsroiui1 = new List<BVSROIUserInput>();
foreach (var b in bvfsroiuis)
                {

                       bvfsroiui1.Add(new BVSROIUserInput()
                    {
                        BVSROIUIId = b.BVSROIUIId,
                        ROIYear = b.ROIYear,
                        ROIYearValue = b.ROIYearValue

                    });
    }
```

my database is done this way
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhqBt.jpg

May i know how can I achieve the expected output? appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can follow the following class structure.

```
public class BusinessValue
{
    [Key]
    public int BVSId { get; set; }

    public List<BVSROI> BVSROI { get; set; }
}

public class BVSROI
{
    [Key]
    public int BVSROIId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string ROIItem { get; set; }
    public UserInput UserInputs { get; set; }
    // Foreign Key
    public int BVSId { get; set; }
    // Navigation property
    public BusinessValue BusinessValue { get; set; }

}
public class UserInput
{
    public int Initial { get; set; 
    public int year1 { get; set; }
    public int year2 { get; set; }
    public int year3 { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Koderzzzz,

This will work but my worry is, if later on we decided to add year4,5,6,7...
then this will mean that I need to adjust the database structure as well.

Comment: For this you can use reflection, means that you need to generate a class at run time based on no. of properties you are getting from the database.

Comment: Do you have any reference or examples on how to do this?

Comment: you can refer this link for reference. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/87b416/dynamically-create-a-class-at-runtime/

Answer (score 1):

You will have to change your BVSROI model.

This is some possible edit. But I'm not sure that this will work, because I don't know how your data is fetched.

```
public class BVSROI
{
   [Key]
   public int BVSROIId { get; set; }
   [Required]
   public string ROIItem { get; set; }
   public string ROIYear { get; set; }
   public Dictionary<string, double> UserInput { get; set; }
   // Foreign Key
   public int BVSId { get; set; }
   // Navigation property
   public BusinessValue BusinessValue { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I am currently using EF code first and data is being fetched from the localDB. When you suggested:
    public Dictionary<string, double> UserInput { get; set; }
does this  mean that i need to create another DB table?

Comment: this is how i fetch the data:
[code] 
          var bvfsrois = (from db.... select bvfsroi).ToList();
            List<BVSROI> bvfsrois1 = new List<BVSROI>();
            foreach (var b in bvfsrois)
            {
                bvfsrois1.Add(new BVSROI()
                {
                    BVSId = b.BVSId,
                    BVSROIId = b.BVSROIId,
                    ROIItem = b.ROIItem,
                    ROIYear = b.ROIYear,
                    ROIYearValue = b.ROIYearValue
                });
            }
[/code]

Comment: So, in the db you keep only the last ROIYearValue? If so, the best approach should be to, as you mentioned, to create another DB table for UserInputs.

Comment: This is my current table:[link] (http://imgur.com/a/M72mU).
If I already have this table what do I need to do with my controller so I don't need to create another table?

Comment: You can't escape the creation of another table. You will have to create table for UserInputs and then to add relationship between BVSROI and UserInputs records.